Generic sync.Map in Go
In one of our projects it became rather painful to use the Go standard library's sync.Map as it lacks type safety, i.e. it became rather tedious to do and check type assertions from the interface. As far as I know, the following port to generics (standalone file) functions properly. Is this an idiomatic use of generics in Go? Are there potential issues with performance?
// Inspired by github.com/SaveTheRbtz/generic-sync-map-go but technically
// written from scratch with Go 1.23's sync.Map.
// Copyright 2024 Runxi Yu (porting it to generics)
// Copyright 2016 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

package cmap

import (
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
)

// Map[K comparable, V comparable] is like a Go map[K]V but is safe for concurrent use
// by multiple goroutines without additional locking or coordination.  Loads,
// stores, and deletes run in amortized constant time.
//
// The Map type is optimized for two common use cases: (1) when the entry for a given
// key is only ever written once but read many times, as in caches that only grow,
// or (2) when multiple goroutines read, write, and overwrite entries for disjoint
// sets of keys. In these two cases, use of a Map may significantly reduce lock
// contention compared to a Go map paired with a separate [Mutex] or [RWMutex].
//
// The zero Map is empty and ready for use. A Map must not be copied after first use.
//
// In the terminology of [the Go memory model], Map arranges that a write operation
// “synchronizes before” any read operation that observes the effect of the write, where
// read and write operations are defined as follows.
// [Map.Load], [Map.LoadAndDelete], [Map.LoadOrStore], [Map.Swap], [Map.CompareAndSwap],
// and [Map.CompareAndDelete] are read operations;
// [Map.Delete], [Map.LoadAndDelete], [Map.Store], and [Map.Swap] are write operations;
// [Map.LoadOrStore] is a write operation when it returns loaded set to false;
// [Map.CompareAndSwap] is a write operation when it returns swapped set to true;
// and [Map.CompareAndDelete] is a write operation when it returns deleted set to true.
//
// [the Go memory model]: https://go.dev/ref/mem
type Map[K comparable, V comparable] struct {
    mu sync.Mutex

    // read contains the portion of the map's contents that are safe for
    // concurrent access (with or without mu held).
    //
    // The read field itself is always safe to load, but must only be stored with
    // mu held.
    //
    // Entries stored in read may be updated concurrently without mu, but updating
    // a previously-expunged entry requires that the entry be copied to the dirty
    // map and unexpunged with mu held.
    read atomic.Pointer[readOnly[K, V]]

    // dirty contains the portion of the map's contents that require mu to be
    // held. To ensure that the dirty map can be promoted to the read map quickly,
    // it also includes all of the non-expunged entries in the read map.
    //
    // Expunged entries are not stored in the dirty map. An expunged entry in the
    // clean map must be unexpunged and added to the dirty map before a new value
    // can be stored to it.
    //
    // If the dirty map is nil, the next write to the map will initialize it by
    // making a shallow copy of the clean map, omitting stale entries.
    dirty map[K]*entry[V]

    // misses counts the number of loads since the read map was last updated that
    // needed to lock mu to determine whether the key was present.
    //
    // Once enough misses have occurred to cover the cost of copying the dirty
    // map, the dirty map will be promoted to the read map (in the unamended
    // state) and the next store to the map will make a new dirty copy.
    misses int
}

// readOnly is an immutable struct stored atomically in the Map.read field.
type readOnly[K comparable, V comparable] struct {
    m       map[K]*entry[V]
    amended bool // true if the dirty map contains some key not in m.
}

// expunged is an arbitrary pointer that marks entries which have been deleted
// from the dirty map.
var expunged = unsafe.Pointer(new(any))

// An entry is a slot in the map corresponding to a particular key.
type entry[V comparable] struct {
    // p points to the interface{} value stored for the entry.
    //
    // If p == nil, the entry has been deleted, and either m.dirty == nil or
    // m.dirty[key] is e.
    //
    // If p == expunged, the entry has been deleted, m.dirty != nil, and the entry
    // is missing from m.dirty.
    //
    // Otherwise, the entry is valid and recorded in m.read.m[key] and, if m.dirty
    // != nil, in m.dirty[key].
    //
    // An entry can be deleted by atomic replacement with nil: when m.dirty is
    // next created, it will atomically replace nil with expunged and leave
    // m.dirty[key] unset.
    //
    // An entry's associated value can be updated by atomic replacement, provided
    // p != expunged. If p == expunged, an entry's associated value can be updated
    // only after first setting m.dirty[key] = e so that lookups using the dirty
    // map find the entry.
    p unsafe.Pointer
}

func newEntry[V comparable](i V) *entry[V] {
    return &entry[V]{p: unsafe.Pointer(&i)}
}

func (m *Map[K, V]) loadReadOnly() readOnly[K, V] {
    if p := m.read.Load(); p != nil {
        return *p
    }
    return readOnly[K, V]{}
}

// Load returns the value stored in the map for a key, or nil if no
// value is present.
// The ok result indicates whether value was found in the map.
func (m *Map[K, V]) Load(key K) (value V, ok bool) {
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    e, ok := read.m[key]
    if !ok && read.amended {
        m.mu.Lock()
        // Avoid reporting a spurious miss if m.dirty got promoted while we were
        // blocked on m.mu. (If further loads of the same key will not miss, it's
        // not worth copying the dirty map for this key.)
        read = m.loadReadOnly()
        e, ok = read.m[key]
        if !ok && read.amended {
            e, ok = m.dirty[key]
            // Regardless of whether the entry was present, record a miss: this key
            // will take the slow path until the dirty map is promoted to the read
            // map.
            m.missLocked()
        }
        m.mu.Unlock()
    }
    if !ok {
        return *new(V), false
    }
    return e.load()
}

func (e *entry[V]) load() (value V, ok bool) {
    p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
    if p == nil || p == expunged {
        return value, false
    }
    return *(*V)(p), true
}

// Store sets the value for a key.
func (m *Map[K, V]) Store(key K, value V) {
    _, _ = m.Swap(key, value)
}

// Clear deletes all the entries, resulting in an empty Map.
func (m *Map[K, V]) Clear() {
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    if len(read.m) == 0 && !read.amended {
        // Avoid allocating a new readOnly when the map is already clear.
        return
    }

    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()

    read = m.loadReadOnly()
    if len(read.m) > 0 || read.amended {
        m.read.Store(&readOnly[K, V]{})
    }

    clear(m.dirty)
    // Don't immediately promote the newly-cleared dirty map on the next operation.
    m.misses = 0
}

// tryCompareAndSwap compare the entry with the given old value and swaps
// it with a new value if the entry is equal to the old value, and the entry
// has not been expunged.
//
// If the entry is expunged, tryCompareAndSwap returns false and leaves
// the entry unchanged.
func (e *entry[V]) tryCompareAndSwap(old V, new V) bool {
    p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
    if p == nil || p == expunged || *(*V)(p) != old { // XXX
        return false
    }

    // Copy the interface after the first load to make this method more amenable
    // to escape analysis: if the comparison fails from the start, we shouldn't
    // bother heap-allocating an interface value to store.
    nc := new
    for {
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, p, unsafe.Pointer(&nc)) {
            return true
        }
        p = atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == nil || p == expunged || *(*V)(p) != old {
            return false
        }
    }
}

// unexpungeLocked ensures that the entry is not marked as expunged.
//
// If the entry was previously expunged, it must be added to the dirty map
// before m.mu is unlocked.
func (e *entry[V]) unexpungeLocked() (wasExpunged bool) {
    return atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, expunged, nil)
}

// swapLocked unconditionally swaps a value into the entry.
//
// The entry must be known not to be expunged.
func (e *entry[V]) swapLocked(i *V) *V {
    return (*V)(atomic.SwapPointer(&e.p, unsafe.Pointer(i)))
}

// LoadOrStore returns the existing value for the key if present.
// Otherwise, it stores and returns the given value.
// The loaded result is true if the value was loaded, false if stored.
func (m *Map[K, V]) LoadOrStore(key K, value V) (actual V, loaded bool) {
    // Avoid locking if it's a clean hit.
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    if e, ok := read.m[key]; ok {
        actual, loaded, ok := e.tryLoadOrStore(value)
        if ok {
            return actual, loaded
        }
    }

    m.mu.Lock()
    read = m.loadReadOnly()
    if e, ok := read.m[key]; ok {
        if e.unexpungeLocked() {
            m.dirty[key] = e
        }
        actual, loaded, _ = e.tryLoadOrStore(value)
    } else if e, ok := m.dirty[key]; ok {
        actual, loaded, _ = e.tryLoadOrStore(value)
        m.missLocked()
    } else {
        if !read.amended {
            // We're adding the first new key to the dirty map.
            // Make sure it is allocated and mark the read-only map as incomplete.
            m.dirtyLocked()
            m.read.Store(&readOnly[K, V]{m: read.m, amended: true})
        }
        m.dirty[key] = newEntry(value)
        actual, loaded = value, false
    }
    m.mu.Unlock()

    return actual, loaded
}

// tryLoadOrStore atomically loads or stores a value if the entry is not
// expunged.
//
// If the entry is expunged, tryLoadOrStore leaves the entry unchanged and
// returns with ok==false.
func (e *entry[V]) tryLoadOrStore(i V) (actual V, loaded, ok bool) {
    p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
    if p == expunged {
        return actual, false, false
    }
    if p != nil {
        return *(*V)(p), true, true
    }

    // Copy the interface after the first load to make this method more amenable
    // to escape analysis: if we hit the "load" path or the entry is expunged, we
    // shouldn't bother heap-allocating.
    ic := i
    for {
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, nil, unsafe.Pointer(&ic)) {
            return i, false, true
        }
        p = atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == expunged {
            return actual, false, false
        }
        if p != nil {
            return *(*V)(p), true, true
        }
    }
}

// LoadAndDelete deletes the value for a key, returning the previous value if any.
// The loaded result reports whether the key was present.
func (m *Map[K, V]) LoadAndDelete(key K) (value V, loaded bool) {
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    e, ok := read.m[key]
    if !ok && read.amended {
        m.mu.Lock()
        read = m.loadReadOnly()
        e, ok = read.m[key]
        if !ok && read.amended {
            e, ok = m.dirty[key]
            delete(m.dirty, key)
            // Regardless of whether the entry was present, record a miss: this key
            // will take the slow path until the dirty map is promoted to the read
            // map.
            m.missLocked()
        }
        m.mu.Unlock()
    }
    if ok {
        return e.delete()
    }
    return value, false
}

// Delete deletes the value for a key.
func (m *Map[K, V]) Delete(key K) {
    m.LoadAndDelete(key)
}

func (e *entry[V]) delete() (value V, ok bool) {
    for {
        p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == nil || p == expunged {
            return value, false
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, p, nil) {
            return *(*V)(p), true
        }
    }
}

// trySwap swaps a value if the entry has not been expunged.
//
// If the entry is expunged, trySwap returns false and leaves the entry
// unchanged.
func (e *entry[V]) trySwap(i *V) (*V, bool) {
    for {
        p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == expunged {
            return nil, false
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, p, unsafe.Pointer(i)) {
            return (*V)(p), true
        }
    }
}

// Swap swaps the value for a key and returns the previous value if any.
// The loaded result reports whether the key was present.
func (m *Map[K, V]) Swap(key K, value V) (previous V, loaded bool) {
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    if e, ok := read.m[key]; ok {
        if v, ok := e.trySwap(&value); ok {
            if v == nil {
                return previous, false
            }
            return *v, true
        }
    }

    m.mu.Lock()
    read = m.loadReadOnly()
    if e, ok := read.m[key]; ok {
        if e.unexpungeLocked() {
            // The entry was previously expunged, which implies that there is a
            // non-nil dirty map and this entry is not in it.
            m.dirty[key] = e
        }
        if v := e.swapLocked(&value); v != nil {
            loaded = true
            previous = *v
        }
    } else if e, ok := m.dirty[key]; ok {
        if v := e.swapLocked(&value); v != nil {
            loaded = true
            previous = *v
        }
    } else {
        if !read.amended {
            // We're adding the first new key to the dirty map.
            // Make sure it is allocated and mark the read-only map as incomplete.
            m.dirtyLocked()
            m.read.Store(&readOnly[K, V]{m: read.m, amended: true})
        }
        m.dirty[key] = newEntry(value)
    }
    m.mu.Unlock()
    return previous, loaded
}

// CompareAndSwap swaps the old and new values for key
// if the value stored in the map is equal to old.
// The old value must be of a comparable type.
func (m *Map[K, V]) CompareAndSwap(key K, old, new V) (swapped bool) {
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    if e, ok := read.m[key]; ok {
        return e.tryCompareAndSwap(old, new)
    } else if !read.amended {
        return false // No existing value for key.
    }

    m.mu.Lock()
    defer m.mu.Unlock()
    read = m.loadReadOnly()
    swapped = false
    if e, ok := read.m[key]; ok {
        swapped = e.tryCompareAndSwap(old, new)
    } else if e, ok := m.dirty[key]; ok {
        swapped = e.tryCompareAndSwap(old, new)
        // We needed to lock mu in order to load the entry for key,
        // and the operation didn't change the set of keys in the map
        // (so it would be made more efficient by promoting the dirty
        // map to read-only).
        // Count it as a miss so that we will eventually switch to the
        // more efficient steady state.
        m.missLocked()
    }
    return swapped
}

// CompareAndDelete deletes the entry for key if its value is equal to old.
// The old value must be of a comparable type.
//
// If there is no current value for key in the map, CompareAndDelete
// returns false (even if the old value is the nil interface value).
func (m *Map[K, V]) CompareAndDelete(key K, old V) (deleted bool) {
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    e, ok := read.m[key]
    if !ok && read.amended {
        m.mu.Lock()
        read = m.loadReadOnly()
        e, ok = read.m[key]
        if !ok && read.amended {
            e, ok = m.dirty[key]
            // Don't delete key from m.dirty: we still need to do the “compare” part
            // of the operation. The entry will eventually be expunged when the
            // dirty map is promoted to the read map.
            //
            // Regardless of whether the entry was present, record a miss: this key
            // will take the slow path until the dirty map is promoted to the read
            // map.
            m.missLocked()
        }
        m.mu.Unlock()
    }
    for ok {
        p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
        if p == nil || p == expunged || *(*V)(p) != old {
            return false
        }
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, p, nil) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// Range calls f sequentially for each key and value present in the map.
// If f returns false, range stops the iteration.
//
// Range does not necessarily correspond to any consistent snapshot of the Map's
// contents: no key will be visited more than once, but if the value for any key
// is stored or deleted concurrently (including by f), Range may reflect any
// mapping for that key from any point during the Range call. Range does not
// block other methods on the receiver; even f itself may call any method on m.
//
// Range may be O(N) with the number of elements in the map even if f returns
// false after a constant number of calls.
func (m *Map[K, V]) Range(f func(key K, value V) bool) {
    // We need to be able to iterate over all of the keys that were already
    // present at the start of the call to Range.
    // If read.amended is false, then read.m satisfies that property without
    // requiring us to hold m.mu for a long time.
    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    if read.amended {
        // m.dirty contains keys not in read.m. Fortunately, Range is already O(N)
        // (assuming the caller does not break out early), so a call to Range
        // amortizes an entire copy of the map: we can promote the dirty copy
        // immediately!
        m.mu.Lock()
        read = m.loadReadOnly()
        if read.amended {
            read = readOnly[K, V]{m: m.dirty}
            copyRead := read
            m.read.Store(&copyRead)
            m.dirty = nil
            m.misses = 0
        }
        m.mu.Unlock()
    }

    for k, e := range read.m {
        v, ok := e.load()
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        if !f(k, v) {
            break
        }
    }
}

func (m *Map[K, V]) missLocked() {
    m.misses++
    if m.misses < len(m.dirty) {
        return
    }
    m.read.Store(&readOnly[K, V]{m: m.dirty})
    m.dirty = nil
    m.misses = 0
}

func (m *Map[K, V]) dirtyLocked() {
    if m.dirty != nil {
        return
    }

    read := m.loadReadOnly()
    m.dirty = make(map[K]*entry[V], len(read.m))
    for k, e := range read.m {
        if !e.tryExpungeLocked() {
            m.dirty[k] = e
        }
    }
}

func (e *entry[V]) tryExpungeLocked() (isExpunged bool) {
    p := atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
    for p == nil {
        if atomic.CompareAndSwapPointer(&e.p, nil, expunged) {
            return true
        }
        p = atomic.LoadPointer(&e.p)
    }
    return p == expunged
}

